# Why is present tense uses rather than past tense in this essay?

Tags: grammar, tense, past-tense

> Grandpa liked chewing tobacco, and he carried a Styrofoam cup with him wherever he went. I **remember** him spitting in that cup with great regularity when I used to spend the night with him and grandmother.

This is one of the sentences that I took from an essay called "Unheeded Advice".

Why is "remember" used as present tense and not past tense as the verb used in the essay is in the past tense?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between 'remember' and 'remembered'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103068/what-is-the-difference-between-remember-and-remembered)

Answer (score 3):

Do you remember the cup now, or was it something you remembered when you passed some Styrofoam cups at the market?  In this case the author is saying he remembers it as he is writing. It doesn't matter when his Grandpa did it; the memory in this case is current, so the tense is present.

Answer (score 0):

Extra note: 'Why is present tense uses rather than past tense in this essay?'
is grammatically incorrect, you should change the 'uses' to 'used'.

It should be, 'Why is present tense **used** rather than past tense in this essay?'

Why? This is because your question is in the **passive voice** of **present simple**.